# Documenting Class Properties in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, documentation, javadoc

Since I switched from Java to Kotlin I had to rewrite my docs. Kotlin has its own documentation format or furthermore it extends normal javadocs as far as I see it. I have checked [the official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#kdoc-syntax) which states that there is a `property` tag which allows you to document the classes properties.

If I have a kdoc looking like this:

```
/**
 * Tablemodel for the Players of a server, only holds two properties:
 *
 *  * Name
 *  * Score
 *
 * @author marcel
 * @since Jan 10, 2018
 * @property playerName Ingame name of the player
 * @property playerScore Ingame score of the player
 */
```

both properties are not part of the rendered kdoc in IntelliJ.

If I move the two properties above `author` and `since`, those will also not show. I don't quite understand why. Is it IntelliJ that is lacking proper kdoc support?

Comment: Are `playerName` and `playerScore` declared _inside_ the class or as its parameters as in the example?

Comment: class Player(var playerName: String, var playerScore: Int) ... but i guess @yole's answer is sufficient, in case it is correct, which i'll test later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as IntelliJ for Java doesn't show you javadocs for all the fields of a class when you invoke the "Show quick documentation" action on the class, IntelliJ for Kotlin doesn't show docs for all properties as part of the class quickdoc. The docs you've added in `@property` tags will be shown if you invoke the "Show quick documentation" action on the property.